# Soap request stuck when run in container

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, soap

Application:
Java maven application that is running on a tomcat server. Is runs a daily job to synchronize data between two systems. The SOAP client has been generated using Eclipse.

I have an application that has been running on a VM for multiple years that I am currently trying to modernize. I have upgraded dependencies, updated some code and am now trying to containerize it as well.

The upgrade went and I can fully run it on a local tomcat server. The problem becomes when I try to run the application running in a container. The container starts up and I can trigger the servlet. The application runs as usual but it gets stuck when sending the SOAP request. This is not an issue when running it outside of the container.

It seems to only be an issue sending that SOAP request when it is inside the container. I receive no error message. It just gets stuck on that specific line.

What could be the issue?

Comment: have you checked the logs of the container to be sure that request reached that container? Or maybe you haven't mapped ports of your container to ports of host machine correctly

Comment: @Ivan I have a print right before the SOAP request and one right after the SOAP request so I can see that the container is reached at least. It prints the one before the SOAP request and then just dies out, so it never reaches the one after the SOAP request.

Comment: Is SOAP request made from container to an outside resource? Have you tried to do curl or wget from container to that URL?

Comment: @Ivan I now tried to curl the URL where I send the SOAP request from the container (exec bash into the container) and I received the WSDL information as a response, so that seem to be no issue.

Comment: Could this be related to included jars? I think I've seen this issue before when running this locally (on another computer) but I added some jars and it was resolved. The weird thing now is that it works on my computer locally but is only an issue inside the container, even though the same dependencies are included.

Comment: If there were missing jars then the program would fail to start or throw exception at runtime.